# How to implement IDisposable in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, implementation, idisposable

I am having my entity framework context in a separate EL Layer, which stands for Entity Layer and then I move to DAL, then BL and my user inteface aspx.cs code page.
I am confused as such how to use IDisposable in the same.
What I am doing till now, supopose in my DAL I have context of my entities.

```
namespace abc
{
    public class Action: IDisposable
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        // all the methods

        public void Dispose()
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it the correct way of doing so?
I am just a naive programmer so help me in learning the same logic.

Comment: Does that `Action` class exist in the DAL?

Comment: No this is just a name of a class, I use entity classes in the methods I create further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would change it a little bit, such as:
Although I have very little experience with implementing the `IDisposable` within the Entity Framework.

```
namespace abc
{
    public class Action: IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed;

        Entities context= new Entities();
        // all the methods

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                    // Dispose other managed resources.
                }
                //release unmanaged resources.
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok let me implemented the same and I will revert as I am actually doing the code analysis and there I was getting this warning, so let me check If I have done it correctly.

Comment: No it is asking me to override the methods.

Comment: which method does it ask to override? From which class?

Comment: Thank you so much I am able to remove those warnings now.

Answer (score 2):

Well in general, yes, your `Dispose` method should dispose of all resources that implement `IDisposable` as well as unmanaged resources (files, etc.)

However, it it usually not a good design to hold on to an EF context as a *resource*.  You will likely have better success if you create a `Context` within your `Action` methods and dispose of it when you're done with it.  Then, if that's your only resource, you don't need to implement `IDisposable` *at all*.

Comment: I am not able to get how to use it, again its confusing.:(

Comment: Your _usage_ is correct; I was just pointing out that EF contexts are typically created and disposed of within a method call, not kept around as the property of a class.