# IDisposable Error in Page_Init()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, idisposable

Well this is really frustrating:
I had earlier posted this question in reference to Entity Framework
 [Using IDisposable in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160200/how-to-implement-idisposable-in-entity-framework) and that error is gone now, but I am unable to get this clear:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String testCondition = Request.QueryString["Type"];
                switch (testCondition)
                {
                    case "A":
                        using (var rpt = new Report())
                        {
                         List<Class> lst= new ActionDBOClass.ActionMethod();    
                         // other code for crstal report view
                         //setting datasource of the same report
                        }
                        break;
                }
         }
    }
```

But then also I am getting warning that I must implement dispose on ActionMethod( In fact I have done the Idisposable implementation in the same class like:

```
 public class ActionDBOClass:IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed = true;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(_disposed);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
                // Dispose other managed resources.
            }
            //release unmanaged resources.
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
```

What else I need to do?
I have similar switch case and this is the first one I am showing.

Comment: Dispose (from IDisposable) should not take any arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use lst outside of the Page_Init method, call lst.Dispose() before returning. Something like:

```
case "A":
    using (var rpt = new Report())
    {
    List<Class> lst= new ActionDBOClass.ActionMethod();    
    // other code for crstal report view
    //setting datasource of the same report
    lst.Dispose();
    }
    break;
```

A safer method would be to do something like using(List lst= new ActionDBOClass.ActionMethod()){... as this will ensure the Dispose is called if an exception is thrown, or to declare lst outside your try block and call Dispose in the finally block if lst != null.

Comment: I am not getting the option of dispose for the List lst, and this is the problem otherwise I had tried that already.

Comment: If you cast lst to IDisposable, does it work? Try

    var disposableList = lst as IDisposable;
    if(disposableList != null) disposableList.Dispose();

Hopefully disposableList will not be null here.
I think that if you alternatively declared lst as a var rather than a List<Class> you would be able to call dispose as above.